# Sort by alphabetically and quantity in same list

Tags: c#, sorting

I need sort by alphabetically (asc) and quantity (desc)  in same list.

My start sample:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Name = "CItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "AItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "BItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "AItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "CItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "AItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "AItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "BItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "BItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "BItem", Age = 10},
                new Item {Name = "BItem", Age = 10}
            };

            items.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Name, y.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

This sample ordered alphabetically only.

Expected Result

1. Name = "BItem", Age = 10
2. Name = "BItem", Age = 10
3. Name = "BItem", Age = 10
4. Name = "BItem", Age = 10
5. Name = "BItem", Age = 10
6. Name = "AItem", Age = 10
7. Name = "AItem", Age = 10
8. Name = "AItem", Age = 10
9. Name = "AItem", Age = 10
10. Name = "CItem", Age = 10
11. Name = "CItem", Age = 10

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why does BItem come before AItem?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, because he has more items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do here is group the items by the name, order the groups by their size, and then flatten out the collection of groups into just the items in those groups.

```
var query = items.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

Comment: your sample do not use the same list.

Comment: @Gus Correct, it does not.  You're more than welcome to materialize the query into a list and store it in the same variable, if that's what you need to do.

Comment: You have to add a ThenBy(group => group.Key) as tie breaker.

Comment: @brz If that's the desired behavior it can be trivially added, yes.  It's not clear if that's needed or not.

Comment: It's in the first line of question.

Comment: @Gus this is the most elegant solution possible.

Comment: @brz It's ambigous what that means.  It seems that the important point here is that the items are ordered *as groups of names* by quantity, thus sorting all items of the same name together as a consequence.  Again, if the OP actually needs groups of the same size to be ordered in a particular manor, it's a trivial line of code that he's already been shown.  If it's not needed, then it's not needed.  He can made the decision.

Comment: I don't see anything about grouping and the expected output in the question seems to imply that no grouping is needed.  It seems to me that a simple `OrderBy` of the Name followed by a `ThenByDescending` of the Age is what is wanted.  What am I missing?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Take a look at the expected output.  That wouldn't result in the correct result.

Comment: @Servy, this solution is good, despite not using the same list. Thanks!